# Order By Desc is not working in SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

[image]I'm using repeaters to show data in webform. But I have a problem with this code. when I `select * data from BidTAble`, it shows in Desc order, but when I use `INNER JOIN`, Desc doesn't work.! :/

Here i've uploaded a picture of  `BidTable` content, i want `Saim` data on the top of table instead of `Awais`

Code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CONN %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT BidTable.BidID, BidTable.RegID, BidTable.CarID, Reg.username, BidTable.BidAmount FROM [BidTable] INNER JOIN Reg ON BidTable.RegID = Reg.ID WHERE ([CarID] = @CarID) ORDER BY [BidTable].[BidAmount] DESC">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CarID" 
              QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Did you check the result only by executing query in ssms? Sample data & query result will help us.

Comment: yes i've checked it, there it works. but when i take username from Reg table using INNER JOIN, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: please post the sample data and how the result looks like with that query

Comment: Try after adding alias in Order by clause. `ORDER BY [BidTable].[BidAmount] DESC`

Comment: Have you used a profiler to see what query is send to the database ?

Comment: I have updated my question. plz reread and do help me cuz i have to submit my FYP tomorrw.  :(

Comment: Show us the actual code, it could be you are re-ordering there as your query looks correct....